# NLTK classification and WordNet with Text Blob

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, categorization

I have the following two sets. The idea is to be able to classify news articles based on a few meta tags I am provided with. For example when I get an article that has "Judge" "5 Years" then it should be classified as a crime story

```
train = [
             ('Honda', 'cars'),
             ('Ford', 'cars'),
             ('Volkswagen', 'cars'),
             ('Courthouse', 'crime'),
             ('Police', 'crime'),
             ('Taurus', 'cars'),
             ('Chevrolet', 'cars'),
             ('Sonic', 'cars'),
             ('Judge', 'crime'),
             ('Jail', 'crime')
             ]
    test = [
            ('Porsche', 'cars'),
            ('Toyota', 'cars'),
            ('Arrest', 'crime'),
            ('Prison', 'crime')
            ]

    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
```

The problem is that when I run this:

```
for a, b in test:
        print a, cl.classify(a)
```

It classifies everything as "cars"

I am sure I am missing the semantic similarity comparision here. I tried using WordNet through text blob.

I ran

```
word = Word("Volkswagen")
for each in word.definitions:
    print each
```

but It does not give me any results.

The question now is:

How do I get WordNet to say that Volkswagen is a car, integrate that into the classifier so that it will realize that Hyndai is also a car and classify it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

WordNet® is a large lexical database of English, car brand names are not part of WordNet, so you can't know that Volkswagen is a car from WordNet. In order to classify a word to category you have to build a vector of features for each train and test example.

Answer (score 1):

There are several aspects to your problem, and you should probably take them one by one:

> "I am sure I am missing the semantic similarity comparision here."

"Semantic similarity" is just one of the many possible improvements you may consider. Note that even for "semantic similarity" there are many different ways you can include it in your model, and not all of them might be straightforward enough to be a small modification of your current NaiveBayes-based solution. Most importantly, though, you are making a mistake of "premature optimization" here. Before you jump into the business of building complicated models with WordNet-matches and whatnot, make sure that your current solution is indeed insufficient.

What you discovered is that if you train a NaiveBayes classifier on a dataset, where the word "Arrest" is not present, the resulting model will have complications classifying this word in the future. However, chances are, with a decently realistic training set you won't find yourself in a situation where a test article will have absolutely no familiar tags too often.

Once you start working with realistic datasets you'll quickly discover that there are many simple down-to-earth things you could try to improve your classifier (fixing the spelling of the tags, first of all) before delving into the "semantic similarity" business, which will complicate your model in many ways without necessarily improving the performance too much.

> but It does not give me any results.

As mentioned in another answer, WordNet simply has no information on the word "Volkswagen". Even if it would, you shouldn't expect that all words in your input would be "familiar", "typo-free", "well-formed", or the like. In the context of what you're doing you should just hope the news article has enough "familiar" tags to recognize its overall topic.

> How do I get WordNet to say that Volkswagen is a car, integrate that into the classifier so that it will realize that Hyndai is also a car and classify it correctly

A possible answer to this particular question is: make your own graph of word associations, add the association "Hyunday"-"Volkswagen", as well as some other things, and use something like a "k-nearest neighbors" model for your classifier.

However, by doing this you will have moved away from your originally claimed task of "classifying news articles by their tags", and your classifier will still fail on the word "Hynday" ;)